# Read More button with arrow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a "Read More" button with a right arrow like the one in the picture. The background color would be white, and the overall button would have to look like this.
[image: button]

I'm using the following code. The arrow here is white, so on my project I can only see the View Profile button, but not the arrow because of the background color.
How could I change the arrow color?

```
<button class="c-btn">View Profile</button>

.c-btn{
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px 48px 12px 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: black;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='7.41' height='12' viewBox='0 0 7.41 12'><path d='M10,6,8.59,7.41,13.17,12,8.59,16.59,10,18l6-6Z' transform='translate(-8.59 -6)' fill='#fff'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 24px center;
}
```

I've tried creating arrows without using links but none looks as good as this one that I got on internet.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your arrow is filled with `#fff` (white).

```
data:image/svg+xml,
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='7.41' height='12' viewBox='0 0 7.41 12'>
    <path d='M10,6,8.59,7.41,13.17,12,8.59,16.59,10,18l6-6Z'
          transform='translate(-8.59 -6)'
          fill='#fff'/>
</svg>"
```

Change the `fill` attribute on the SVG:

```
data:image/svg+xml,
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='7.41' height='12' viewBox='0 0 7.41 12'>
    <path d='M10,6,8.59,7.41,13.17,12,8.59,16.59,10,18l6-6Z'
          transform='translate(-8.59 -6)'
          fill='#ff4a00'/>
</svg>"
```

... or whatever hex color you'd like the arrow to be.